# How to sort shell history by recency and remove duplicates?

Tags: awk, sort, command-history

I don't really know awk, but my attempt so far

`history | awk '!x[<everything except first column which is the order>]++' | sort -r`

Answer (score 2):

Does it need to be awk?

```
history | tail -n 50 | sort -r -n | cut -d " " -f4- | sort -u
```

basically

1. Reverse Sort history using the numeric prefix
2. Remove spaces
3. Remove leading numbers
4. Remove duplicates

Alternatively, you can do the following based on this [previously answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124869/sort-history-on-number-of-occurences)

```
history | sort -rn | sed -e 's/ *[0-9][0-9]* *//' | uniq | less
```